# Flutter: selectable (rich) text containing action buttons

Tags: flutter

Inside a selectable block of text, is it possible to add action buttons (or more precisely, an action icons)?

I'm actually using the `SelectableText.rich` and `TextSpan` widgets. But they doesn't allow adding buttons or any other than a `TextSpan`.

I also want to avoid using multiple `SelectableText.rich` and place my button between them, because it will break the "select all" feature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't do this with a single `SelectableText`. I tried using `WidgetSpan` as per the following snippet but get the following error.

```dart
const SelectableText.rich(
    TextSpan(children: [
        TextSpan(text: "Some text"),
        WidgetSpan(child: Icon(Icons.face)),
        TextSpan(text: "Some more text"),
    ])
)
```

[image: SelectableText only supports TextSpan]

---

To compare, if we were to replace `SelectableText` with `Text` we'd get:

[image]